Selenium unable to locate element in Edge Browser Version 125
I have a C# application where we've upgraded the Browser from version 101 to 125. There is an Selenium Test Solution where all the tests pass but now fail.
These failing tests are erroring on locating and element by CSS Selector and giving the message unable to locate element. Looking through one of the tests in debug the test starts running, does some processing on the page, the page refreshes and is meant to carry on, but doesn't. The code we have is
var element = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 10);
element.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selec)));

Now, I have tried modifying by using expected conditions with an XPath by id to the element but still getting the same error message.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

you should add value of "selec" and the code for XPATH method you tried, along with the markup of the DOM at the time you run this command.  (right-click in browser, choose "Inspect" copy/paste relevant markup into your question)  You mention Edge explicitly.  Does that mean the code works/behaves differently in Chrome?

Does the same problem occur on Chrome? Please provide me with a reproducible example if it is convenient. In addition, I suggest that you should update Edge and EdgeDriver to the latest version before testing. You can also refer to this official link, which describes the use of different attributes to locate elements.
The link: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/
